# PSQL - Modify data type of column

Tags: postgresql, psql, psqlodbc

```
ALTER TABLE user_login ALTER COLUMN dob date;
```

Is this correct query in psql to modify the data type of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to include `TYPE`. It should be

```
ALTER TABLE user_login ALTER COLUMN dob TYPE date
```

See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html). You're probably confused with `ADD COLUMN` where you can omit the `TYPE`.

Comment: I got error like this-->ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALTER"
LINE 2: ALTER TABLE user_login ALTER COLUMN dob TYPE date;

Comment: ERROR:  column "dob" cannot be cast to type "date"